# Magento: I want to search customer by phone number regardless of spaces

Tags: search, magento, admin

I want to search customer in admin panel by customer billing phone
but i need to search it regardless of spaces

like it should search with spaces like 123 456 789
and if admin enters 123456789 then it also have to search so spaces don't matter

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Place some frontend javascript in checkout to ensure that your phone numbers are formatted in a standard way, e.g. area code + " " + number. Use some extra boxes that add the area code box plus a space and the number into a hidden version of the telephone number box using onchange so that the visible boxes don't get submitted with the form, just the hidden box that has a space after the area code. Also get your js to remove any extra spaces in the number field. Then take some time to format the numbers already present in the database. Now, in the backend it will be easy to find numbers.